# How to dynamically increase or decrease MUI Grid column size?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Wanted to widen Part 2 dynamically so `xs` or part 1 becomes 3 and part 2 becomes 9:

```
<Grid container>
  <Grid item xs={6}>Part 1</Grid>
  <Grid item xs={6}>Part 2</Grid>
</Grid>
```

I tried to use state to keep the value but got error as

```
<Grid item xs={{sizeOfPanel}}>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xs={{sizeOfPanel}}
```

The code above means passing an object with the property `sizeOfPanel` to the `xs` prop, but because `xs` is a boolean or a `GridSize` (not an object), I assume this is what you mean:

```
xs={sizeOfPanel}
```

**EDIT:** For typescript users, since `xs` from `Grid` accepts a [`GridSize`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e0cdcd130db60d252c4382570844ea7278649a08/packages/mui-material/src/Grid/Grid.d.ts#L13) (`1` -> `12` constants), not just any number, so to fix the type error, you have to assert the type for dynamic values:

```
import Grid, { GridSize } from "@mui/material/Grid";
```

```
xs={sizeOfPanel as GridSize}
```

Here is a full example for you to reference:

```
const [xs, setXs] = React.useState(6);

return (
  <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
    <Button
      variant="contained"
      onClick={() => setXs((xs) => (xs === 12 ? 0 : ++xs))}
    >
      update
    </Button>
    <Grid container spacing={2}>
      <Grid
        item
        xs={xs as GridSize}
        sx={
          xs === 0 && {
            display: "none"
          }
        }
      >
        <Item>xs={xs}</Item>
      </Grid>
      <Grid
        item
        xs={(12 - xs) as GridSize}
        sx={
          xs === 12 && {
            display: "none"
          }
        }
      >
        <Item>xs={12 - xs}</Item>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Box>
);
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: sizeOfPanel is number but I got the compilation error as Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'boolean | GridSize | undefined'... so not sure how to make it work